# Storing form data with file uploads

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, multipartform-data

So i'm building out a middle-man script between an  form and the mysql database.

Long story short, there's a form and a table and this script handles all the fields updates the forms respective database table with the submitted form data and if there are any files, uploads the files to a destination while creating a pointer to it in the database.

That part i have done, and it works nicely. However, i realize that there's a slight issue with my idea here.

When a user submits a form

```
[first_name]
[last_name]
[email]
[file1]
[file2]
```

I first load the form data, than upon success i upload the files.

But if the file upload for whatever reason fails, too large, wrong type, times-out or even a bug. I'm left with form data but no associated files.

I could catch the file upload error and then remove the inserted form data record, but what if the error is an intentional quit. Or user error where they close a tab/browser.

Is there a way to do both "insert form data into db table" and "upload files" but only if they both have 100% of succeeding?

If anyone can simply point me in the right direction, that will help plenty.

Hope i'm making sense!
Thanks!

Comment: sure, but you'd have to have the user upload and fill in the fields in the SAME form. otherwise you're dealing with two completely separate requests, and will have to put in a bunch of logic to clean up if one or the other fails.

Comment: That's how it is, the same form contains user input fields and file upload fields.

Answer (score 1):

Either use a single form to upload parameters and the file, or use session to save parameters after the 1st form is submitted instead of saving the data directly to the database.

Then you try to save the file to its final location. If it fails, you can offer the user to try again. If it succeeds, then you have the pointer to its location.

Then, you try to save the form data to the database. If it fails, then you can delete the uploaded file as well using the path you obtained when you saved the file.

Comment: Hmmmm, true doing the reverse makes it a bit easier if the uses craps out mid-upload. However, are sessions necessary?

Comment: Use session only if you use multiple forms to upload the data.